# Restrictions Between for Date in Hibernate Criteria

Tags: hibernate

Hello I am using hibernate in my example.For bean Table Audit Trial I want to fetch audit trial between a date range with inclusion of upper & lower limits.
My code is like below

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(AuditTrail.class);

criteria.add(Restrictions.between("auditDate", sDate, eDate));
```

My starting date is `25/11/2010`. and end date is `25/05/2011`.But it is only giving the result up to `24/05/2011`.It is not performing inclusive search.Any other way to do this.
I am using SQL server.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I assume your auditDate is in fact a timestamp. If it's the case, then this is normal, because 25/05/2011 means 25/05/2011 at 0 o'clock (in the morning). So, of course, every row having an audit timestamp in the date 25/05/2011 is after 0 o'clock in the morning.

I would add 1 day to your end date, and use `auditDate >= sDate and auditDate < eDate`.

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("auditDate", sDate)); 
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("auditDate", eDate));
```

Comment: *Protip:* if you don't have to deal with the time component like the OP above, you could just use `le(..)` (instead of `lt(..)` + messy date arithmetic).

Answer (score 2):

`criteria.add(Restrictions.between("DATE(auditDate)", sDate, eDate));` use this for ignoring time from date.

Comment: This gives error: "could not resolve property: DATE(auditDate)"

Answer (score 1):

```
 criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("fromDate", DateUtil.persianToGregorian(currentDate)));
 criteria.add(Restrictions.le("toDate",  DateUtil.persianToGregorian(currentDate)));

 return criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 1):

add one more day to end date

```
 @Autowired
 private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 String startDate = "2019-07-31 ";
 String endDate = "2019-08-24 ";

 Date fromDate = format.parse(fromDate);

 /* Add one more day to the end date*/

 Date to =format.parse(endDate);
 Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
 today.setTime(dateto);
 today.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);

 Date toDate= format.parse(format.format(today.getTime()));

 Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(model.class);
 crit.add(Restrictions.between("dateFieldName", fromDate, toDate));
 List result = crit.list();
```