# calender show results like date1<= results<date2

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat

I used two calender for starting date and finishing as below,

```
date.Ic.add(Restrictions.between("islemZamani", date1, date2));
```

However result of this criteria has results of date1 and between of them,not include  results of date2.I mean ,It shows **date1<= results. I want date1<= results<=date2.** So I tried SimpleDateFormat like this;

```
    String tar1 = new String();
    String tar2 = new String();
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Istanbul");
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(tz);
    tar1 = dateFormat.format(date1);
    tar2 = dateFormat.format(date2);
    tar1 = tar1.substring(11, 18) + "000000";
    tar2 = tar2.substring(11, 18) + "235959";

    c.add(Restrictions.between("islemZamani", tar1, tar2));
```

Now It gives NullPointerException.How can i solve this problem? Do you suggest any different way from SimpleDateFormat? Thanka for any reply.

Comment: Please share error/ log trace.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122808/restrictions-between-for-date-in-hibernate-criteria) will help you out

Comment: Your date1 and date2 are java.util.Date ?

Comment: To avoid the substring, use "HH:mm:ss" as format

Comment: @Gamb how can add 1 day to my date2(string)?Actually I tried like this tar2.substring(11, 18) + "235959" but still does not work

Comment: @Pignic yes ,they are java.util.Date

Comment: @Pignic "HH:mm:ss" did't work also

Comment: Rather than using `SimpleDateFormat`, I suggest you work on the date directly through the use of the `Calendar` Java class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a string to manipulate date is too complicated and may case a loooot of problems.
Use only java.util.Date and/or java.util.GregorianCalendar.

Try this :

```
GregorianCalendar calendar1 = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar1.setTime(date1);
// Edit the calendar1 here if you want to

GregorianCalendar calendar2 = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar2.setTime(date2);
calendar2.add(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Istanbul");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(tz);

String tar1 = dateFormat.format(calendar1.getTime());
String tar2 = dateFormat.format(calendar2.getTime());

c.add(Restrictions.between("islemZamani", tar1, tar2));
```

But without the trace, I'm not sure this will solve your problem...

And, if it's possible, use the date instead of the string in your restriction.