# HTTP Status 400 - type Status report message description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. Apache Tomcat/7.0.73

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm new in Spring and I want to search and display records between two dates in my .jsp with Hibernate and Criteria, but it doesn't work.

It returns this error:

> HTTP Status 400 - type Status report message description The request
>   sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. Apache Tomcat/7.0.73

Can you help me please?

Here's my code:
CancelacionDAO.java

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import cl.helloworld.pojo.Cancelacion;
public interface CancelacionDAO {
    public List<TCancelacionNX> findByFecha(Date fecha_anterior, Date fecha_siguiente);
}
```

CancelacionDAOImpl.java

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import cl.helloworld.pojo.Cancelacion;

@Transactional
@Repository
public class CancelacionDAOImpl implements CancelacionDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<TCancelacionNX> findByFecha(Date dateFrom, Date dateTo) {

        Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(Cancelacion.class);

        crit.add(Restrictions.between("FECHA", fecha_anterior, fecha_siguiente));

        return crit.list();
    }
<br>
}
```

Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/cuadratura/search")
    public String handleCuadratura(@ModelAttribute("cancelacion") Cancelacion cancelacionForm,
            Model model, RedirectAttributes ra, @RequestParam("dateFrom") Date dateFrom, @RequestParam("dateTo") Date dateTo){

        List<Cancelacion> cancelaciones = cancelacionService.findByFecha(dateFrom, dateTo);

        Cancelacion cancelacion = new Cancelacion();
        model.addAttribute("cancelacion", cancelacion);
        model.addAttribute("cancelaciones", cancelaciones);

        return "redirect:/cuadratura";
    }
```

View.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <c:url value="/resources/images" var="images" />
    <img src="${images}/logo.png"/>

        <sf:form class="form-inline" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/cuadratura/search" method="post" commandName="tcancelacionnx">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>From:</label>
                <input name="dateFrom" type="text"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>To:</label>
                <input name="dateTo" type="text"/>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Generar Cuadratura">
        </sf:form>
        <br/>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Seq Fichero</th>
                    <th>Num Operacion</th>
                    <th>Código Contrato</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${cancelaciones}" var="cancelacion">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${cancelacion.seq_fichero_cierre}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${cancelacion.num_operacion}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${cancelacion.codigo_contrato}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${cancelacion.fecha}"/></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="page-header">

    </div>  
    <div id="footer">
      <div class="container">

        <p class="text-muted credit"></p>

      </div>
    </div>

<script src="webjars/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to expand on "this not work".

Comment: HTTP Status 400 -

type Status report

message

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.73

Comment: Try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122808/restrictions-between-for-date-in-hibernate-criteria

Comment: Okay, so there is probably some stacktrace written to the log/console?