# Unable to fetch data between two dates in Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am surprisingly unable to fetch the sum of a field between two Dates
My method is:

```
public static double getTotalfeeIncome(Date fromDate, Date toDate) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        double total = 0.0;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(StudentFees.class);
            cr.add(Restrictions.eq("delFlg", "N"));
            cr.add(Restrictions.between("paymentDate", fromDate, toDate));
            log.debug(fromDate);
            log.debug(toDate);
            total = (Double) cr.setProjection(Projections.sum("paymentAmt")).uniqueResult();
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception asd) {
            log.debug(asd.getMessage());
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return total;
    }
```

When I try to get the value:

```
double feeIncome = Expense.getTotalfeeIncome(fdate, tdate);
```

returns 0 but there is data between the two dates. There seem to be an error that is not getting printed out in my `catch` section. My logger output is:

```
[edulogger] [11 Mar 2017 - 18:54:48] [DEBUG][dao.Expense][getTotalfeeIncome] - Sat Mar 11 00:00:00 EAT 2017 
2017-03-11 18:54:48,334 DEBUG com.orig.edu.dao.Expense edulogger:182 - Sat Mar 11 00:00:00 EAT 2017
[edulogger] [11 Mar 2017 - 18:54:48] [DEBUG][dao.Expense][getTotalfeeIncome] - Sat Mar 11 00:00:00 EAT 2017 
2017-03-11 18:54:48,338 DEBUG com.orig.edu.dao.Expense edulogger:183 - Sat Mar 11 00:00:00 EAT 2017
Hibernate: select sum(this_.payment_amt) as y0_ from edutek.student_fees this_ where this_.del_flg=? and this_.payment_date between ? and ?
[edulogger] [11 Mar 2017 - 18:54:48] [DEBUG][dao.Expense][getTotalfeeIncome] -  
2017-03-11 18:54:48,455 DEBUG com.orig.edu.dao.Expense edulogger:187 -
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following

```
cr.add(criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("paymentDate", fromDate))); 
cr.add(criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("paymentDate", toDate)));
```

instead of

```
cr.add(Restrictions.between("paymentDate", fromDate, toDate));
```

### UPDATE:

```
cr.add(Restrictions.between("DATE(paymentDate)", fromDate, toDate));
```

Resource Link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6122906/2293534

Comment: I am getting the same results. Only the query output changed but no data is selected.

Comment: Would you please check updated section @ErrorNotFoundException

Comment: This returns an error `could not resolve property: DATE(paymentDate) of: com.orig.edu.jpa.StudentFees`

Comment: @ErrorNotFoundException Your start date and end date may be same. Please check the log again.