# Date between two properties in Hibernate Criteria API

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, oracle11g

I am trying to fetch the record where the dates is between two fields in My database using Criteria API. I need to build a query that looks like:

```
select tran_date_bal from eod_acct_bal_table where acid = <MyAcid> and <BalanceDate> between eod_date and end_eod_date;
```

I am stuck on the bit of getting the Date Criteria as the provided `between` does not allow two properties. Here is what I have so far:

```
private static double getEndOfDayBalanceAsAtDate(String foracid, Date BalanceDate) {
        double balance = 0;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(EodAcctBalTable.class);
            cr.add(Restrictions.eq("acid", getAcid(foracid)));
            cr.add(Restrictions.between());//****Stuck Here***********
            balance = (Double) cr.setProjection(Projections.property("tranDateBal")).uniqueResult();
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception asd) {
            log.debug(asd.getMessage());
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return balance;
    }
```

How do I generate my query while sticking to Criteria?

Comment: Did you try `(Restrictions.between("yourDate", DateBegin, DateEnd))` ?

Comment: `YourDate` cannot go as the first parameter of `between` as this is Looking for a field property in the EOD_ACCT_BAL_TABLE

Comment: and `BalanceDate` is a field property  in the EOD_ACCT_BAL_TABLE  So !

Comment: No `BalanceDate` is an Input Parameter of Type Date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrictions Between for Date in Hibernate Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122808/restrictions-between-for-date-in-hibernate-criteria)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Restrictions.between`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#between-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) only accepts values, so you can't use it here, I'm afraid.

You can build an equivalent query with [`le`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#le-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) and [`ge`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#ge-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-):

```
cr.add(Restrictions.le("eod_date", /** balance date **/));
cr.add(Restrictions.ge("eod_date_end", /** balance date **/));
```

Another option is to use an [`sqlRestriction`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#sqlRestriction-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-org.hibernate.type.Type-):

```
cr.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("? between eod_date and eod_date_end", /** balance date **/, StandardBasicTypes.DATE ));
```

Comment: balanceDate is an Input Parameter of Date type not a field.

Comment: Yeah that looks better, sorry I have never used wilcards in hibernate before how is the BalanceDate assigned to the wildcard?

Comment: @ErrorNotFoundException This overload accepts a single parameter, you only need to pass the balance date into a method (in place of a comment).

Comment: That I know, I am asking about the SqlRestriction.

Comment: @ErrorNotFoundException yes, it accepts the balance date (look for `/** balance date **/` in example call) as a parameter value (the value for `?`). See [the javadoc for method](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#sqlRestriction-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-org.hibernate.type.Type-)